# Laravel Marge & Map problems

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have two kinds of problems that I'm trying to fix. 
**First thing:**
One of them is using merge to combine two objects together in order to get rid of duplication of lines:

```
$lead -> foreach of $leads = Lead::all();
$tempUser = DB::table('users')
            ->select('phone','email', DB::raw('CONCAT(users.first_name, " ", users.last_name) AS name'))
            ->where('id', $lead->customer_id)
            ->first();
$lead->name = $tempUser->name;
$lead->phone = $tempUser->phone;
$lead->email = $tempUser->email;
```

searching for a way using a merge function to get rid of this 3 lines:

```
$lead->name = $tempUser->name;
$lead->phone = $tempUser->phone;
$lead->email = $tempUser->email;
```

**Second thing:**
I'm trying to use map function in order to make an array of users list for the selection field. It makes me an array in another array and I don't have any idea how to get rid of it.

```
$mailingLists = MailingList::select('id', 'name')->get();
$lists = collect($mailingLists)->map(function($mailingLists){
    return [$mailingLists->id => $mailingLists->name];
})->toArray();
```

Output:

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [1] => Mailing List
>           )
>       [1] => Array
>           (
>               [3] => Mailing List 2
>           )
>   )

desire:

> Array
>   (
>       [1] => Mailing List
>       [3] => Mailing List 2
>   )

Thanks for the help & support...!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [reduce](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-reduce) instead :

```
$lists = collect($mailingLists)->reduce(function($carry, $mailingLists){
    if (!$carry[$mailingLists->id]) {
        $carry[$mailingLists->id] = $mailingLists->name;
    }
    return $carry;
}, []);
```

For the first thing you can use `fill` or `update` method (fill will not save the informations, you have to call `save`method mefore)
For the database call, use `pluck` method :

```
->where('id', $lead->customer_id)
->pluck('name', 'phone', 'email') // getting only these fields
->first();
$lead->update($tempUser); // update direcly with tempUser fields
```

Comment: What are the differents between the map and the reduce? Why isn't it working with map? Thanks!

Comment: It's because when you map your data the array will always do the same size, you will transform all the elements inside the array but not the array itself, with reduce, you are reducing the entiere array into a new value, here an array.

Comment: Oh really thanks, It works perfect. What about the first thing? Do you have any idea or way to help me with it? Thanks!

Comment: I'll check it right now, huge thanks. If I would like to add to $lists array one more key => value at the top of the array like this: ' ' => 'empty'. What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: in the reduce method, the last argument of the function is the default value, so you just have to give instead of `[]`an array with this first key : `[ '' => 'empty' ]`

Comment: Huge thanks it works, There is a problem with the plusk: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::plusk() and with the fill: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::fill() must be of the type array, object given, called. I'm tring to load everything in the view. Thanks!

Comment: it's `pluck` not `plusk` :)

Comment: still error with fill function: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::fill() must be of the type array, string given, called

Comment: The plusk function returns me only the value of the 'phone' key, nothing else.

Comment: hmmmm maybe try to remove `pluck` and use `toArray()` instead `$lead->update($tempUser->toArray());` because you already select the good fields

Comment: I fixed this by using this function: $lead->fill((array) $tempUser); huge thanks, you really helped me!